# Android Retrofit OkHttpClient Interceptor Add Header Gets Error "HTTP 403 Forbidden"

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

So, my goal is to embed the `api key` into my `Retrofit` object so that I don't need to manually append it as query parameter inside **each request function**, then I did the following (learn from: https://proandroiddev.com/headers-in-retrofit-a8d71ede2f3e):

```
private val interceptor = Interceptor { chain ->
    val newRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().run {
        addHeader("api_key", Constants.API_KEY)
        build()
    }

    chain.proceed(newRequest)
}

private val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().run {
    connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    readTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    addInterceptor(interceptor)    //<- apply Interceptor
    build()
}

//apply the okHttpClient to my Retrofit object...
```

But it failed and gave this error: `HTTP 403 Forbidden`.

**PS: Before adding this `Interceptor` everything works fine**

---

Before:

```
@GET("neo/rest/v1/feed")
suspend fun getAsteroidsResult(
    @Query("start_date") startDate: String,
    @Query("end_date") endDate: String, 
    @Query("api_key") apiKey: String = Constants.API_KEY
): ResponseBody
```

Comment: Can you share how the api_key was added before?

Comment: Your first approach was adding the api_key as a query parameter.  The second approach is adding it as a header.  They are not the same.  Read more here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40492782/what-is-the-difference-between-http-parameters-and-http-headers

Comment: @eimmer But what about the article I mentioned?

Comment: The article only seems to outline how to add a value to the header.  Am I missing something relevant?

Comment: last I knew you read in values passed in the two different ways differently on the server side.  So, you would have to update the server code to read in the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add log interceptor and set the log level and provide a log?

```
 compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.2.0'
```

And sth like this :

```
 OkHttpClient.Builder okBuilder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
     okBuilder.addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC).setLevel
             (HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY).setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS))
```